# If all partial derivatives exist at each point of $A$, then $f \in \mathcal C^1 (A)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

This thread is meant to record a question that I feel interesting during my self-study. I'm very happy to receive your suggestion and comments.

---

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be open convex, $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ convex.

- **Theorem 1:**  If all partial derivatives
  $$
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(a) \quad(i=1, \ldots, d)
  $$
  exist at $a \in A$, then $f$ is Fréchet differentiable at $a$.
- **Theorem 2:** If all partial derivatives exist at each point of $A$, then $f \in \mathcal C^1 (A)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proof of Theorem 1:** Clearly, $f$ is locally Lipschitz on $A$. We need the following results.

[Lemma 1:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4465343/let-a-be-an-open-convex-subset-of-a-normed-space-if-fa-to-mathbb-r-is-co) Let $X$ be a normed space, $A \subset X$ convex open, and $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ convex continuous at $a\in A$. If the directional derivative $f^{\prime}(a) [v]$ exists for every direction $v \in X$, then $f$ is Gâteaux differentiable at $a$.

[Lemma 2:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464816/let-f-be-lipschitz-around-a-in-mathbb-rd-then-f-is-fr%c3%a9chet-differentia) Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be open, $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $a \in A$. Assume that $f$ is Lipschitz on some neighborhood of $a$. Then $f$ is Fréchet differentiable at $a$ if and only if $f$ is Gâteaux differentiable at $a$.

By **Lemma 1**, $f$ is is Gâteaux differentiable at $a$. By **Lemma 2**, $f$ is Fréchet differentiable at $a$.

---

**Proof of Theorem 2:** By **Theorem 1**, $f$ is Fréchet differentiable on $A$.

[Lemma 3:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4479232/strong-convergence-of-subgradients-of-a-convex-fr%c3%a9chet-differentiable-function-o) Let $X$ be a normed space, $A \subset X$ convex open, and $f: A\to \mathbb R$ convex continuous. If $f$ is Fréchet differentiable at each point of $A$, then $f \in \mathcal{C}^{1}(A)$.

By **Lemma 3**, $\partial f$ is continuous. This completes the proof.

Comment: Actually both theorems are false. No, its not clear, not even true, that $f$ must be locally Lipschitz.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Please see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336194/every-convex-function-is-locally-lipschitz-mathbbrn) thread.

Comment: I missed the assumption that $f$ is convex, sorry.